# Контрол выбора TOP 10 из БД

Tags: devexpress

Подскажите как можно организовать что-то вроде GridLookUpEdit Только чтобы в него загружались не все возможные данные из базы данных, а первые 10 совпавших при чем при начале ввода в поле (поиск) предлагались новые TOP 10 вариантов

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, SearchLookUp это интересно, 1)но скажем если данных 100 000 то даже первая буква введенная в поиск выдаст огромное количество строк, а можно скажем начинать загрузку с 3 введенных букв?
2)Или можно как то переписать немного логику поведения LookUp, например создав класс наследник от этого контрола?
3)И еще можно ли как то поместить в строку поиска предопределенное значение, скажем мы вводим текст в обычное текстовое поле, реализуем всю логику и заполнение BindingSource и потом передаем введенный текст в SearchLookUp и продолжаем поиск уже из небольшого количества данных?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [SearchLookUpEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsSearchLookUpEdittopic) в [Instant Feedback](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument8893) режиме. Тогда будут из базы загружаться не все данные, а только те которые необходимы. То есть будет происходить загрузка по мере необходимости.  Конечно, вы не сможете указать что именно 10 записей надо грузить, но можете быть уверены, что строчки, которые не видимы  - грузиться не будут.